# mongodb - using join on a local variable

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm using node.js and mongodb, I have an array of objects which holds the names of an id. Let's say below is my array

```
let names = [ 
    { value: 1, text: 'One' },
    { value: 2, text: 'Two' },
    { value: 3, text: 'Three' },
    { value: 4, text: 'Gour' }
]
```

And this is my query result of a collection using `$group` which gives me the distinct values.

```
[ 
    { _id: { code: '1', number: 5 } },
    { _id: { code: '2', number: 5 } },
    { _id: { code: '3', number: 2 } },
    { _id: { code: '4', number: 22 } },
]
```

`$lookup` let's us to join the data from a different collection, but in my case I have an array which holds the `text` value for each of the codes which I got from the query.

Is there a way we can map the `text` from the array to the results from mongodb?

Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

MongoDB query which I was trying

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _Id: id
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            localField:         "code",
            from:               names,
            foreignField:       "value",
            as:                 "renderedNames"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : { 
            "_id": { 
                code:       "$code",
                number:  "$number"
            } 
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Is it  a single document, or 4 documents in the first snippet? Which fields are looked up? It would be simpler to answer if you add an example of the lookup stage you are trying to write.

Comment: I'm trying to get the `text` from names array to the mongodb results which I have using `value` and `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variable lives in nodejs app, and mongodb knows nothing about it.

It looks like it belongs to representation layer, where you want to show codes as meaningful names. The mapping should be done there. I believe [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is the most suitable here:

```
names.find(name => name.code === doc._id.code).text
```

If the names are not truly variable but quite constant, you can move it to own collection, e.g. `codeNames`:

```
db.codeNames.insert([ 
    { _id: "1", text: 'One' },
    { _id: "2", text: 'Two' },
    { _id: "3", text: 'Three' },
    { _id: "4", text: 'Gour' }
]);
```

and use $lookup as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _Id: id
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id": {
                code:       "$code",
                number:  "$number"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            localField:         "_id.code",
            from:               "codeNames",
            foreignField:       "_id",
            as:                 "renderedNames"
        }
    }
]);
```

If none of the above suit your usecase, you can pass the names to the database in each request to map names db-side, but you must be really really sure you cannot use 2 previous options:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _Id: id
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id": {
                code:       "$code",
                number:  "$number"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            renderedNames: { $filter: { 
                input: [ 
                    { value: "1", text: 'One' },
                    { value: "2", text: 'Two' },
                    { value: "3", text: 'Three' },
                    { value: "4", text: 'Gour' }
                ], 
                as: "name", 
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$name.value", "$_id.code" ] } 
            }
         }
      }
    },
]);
```

As a side note, I find `$match: {_Id: id}` quite confusing, especially followed by `$group`. If `_Id` is `_id`, it is unique. You can have no more than 1 document after this stage, so there is not too much to group really.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the `_id`, while masking the real code. I didn't notice that. The 3rd method is what I was looking for. It worked now for me, thanks a lot :) +1

Comment: Glad it helped, but I feel like I need to emphasise that the 3rd one is the worst in terms of performance.

Comment: Oh, I just started on mongo db few days ago. If you can give me a better one than that. It'll really help to get more knowledge on mongo. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not specific to mongo db. I am pretty sure the first option is what you are after. If you need to **display** fancy names instead of codes, such logic should live in representation layer. Some would go as far as moving it to css, but it might be a bit too extreme. I'd apply mapping serverside at application level.

Comment: It is returning me only one item in the array, so If I loop I just insert it to the existing. It works and efficient. Thank you :)